# regex to catch beetween tags, but not certain chatacter

Tags: regex

I have a text like

```
>toto< => match `toto`
```

and

```
>{toto}< => do not match anything
```

So I want to create regex that only catch the text in beetween `>` `<` but that do NOT start with `<{` `}>`

I tried to use `>(.*?)<`

I do not know what is ignoring the regex if it start like this, as `>to{to<` this should match `to{to`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
>(?!\{[^<>]*\}<)([^<>]+)<
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gmKQj7/3).

**Details**:

- `>` - a `>` char
- `(?!\{[^<>]*\}<)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `{`, then zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` and then a `}<` string
- `([^<>]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `<` - a `<` char.

Comment: sorry, this looks goodindeed in the demo, but in Visual code I have `error lone quantifier brackets`

Comment: this matches `>{}<`

Comment: ah the update looks nice, thanks, I will check the changes

Comment: @Bobby I addressed both remarks here and updated the demo link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex. This checks if `{` present after `>`, if yes it checks if `}` not present before `<`, and captures all the characters between `>` and `<` in group 1.

```regex
>(([^{])?.*(?(2)|[^}]))<
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gmKQj7/4)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could try following regex.

```
>(?!{)(.*?)(?!})<
```

**Details**:

- `>(?!{)` matches string which does not start with `>{`
- `(?!})<`: matches string which does not end with `}<`
- `(.*?)`: matches any characters as few as possible

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9XLnFL/2)